# Two Spring Controller Methods, One Returns 200, Other Returns 404. Only Differ By The Mapping URL

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

I have two controller methods shown below, the `/garages/a` works when I post JSON to it (response is a 200) but the `/garages/a/brand` gives a 404.
They only differ by the mapping value.

I am using Spring 4.1.4.RELEASE and Java config. I am not using Spring Boot.

Controller methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/garages/a", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Content-Type = application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Garage specificGaragePost(
@RequestBody Garage garage) {
    return garage;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/garages/a/brand", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Content-Type = application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Garage specificGarageBrandPost(
    @RequestBody Garage garage) {
    return garage;
}
```

Garage class

```
public class Garage {
    private String id;
    private String brand;
    private List<Fuel> fuels;
    private double[] location;

    //Getters and setters left out for brevity
```

Example JSON (works for the /garages/a URL but not /garages/a/brand)

```
 {
     "id": "some-id",
     "brand": "brand",
     "fuels": [],
     "location": [0,0]
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when it finds `/garages/a/brand`, it treats it as `/garages/a/` with a parameter brand, but `/garages/a/` doesn't accept any parameters.

Comment: No, it doesn't, not unless there's a URI variable involved, which there isn't here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the @RequestMapping sintax. Remove the blanks in the headers section:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/garages/a", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Content-Type=application/json", produces = "application/json")

@RequestMapping(value = "/garages/a/brand", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Content-Type=application/json", produces = "application/json")
```

Even better, instead of using headers for filtering the Content-Type, use consumes which is specific for that purpose:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/garages/a", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes= "application/json", produces = "application/json")

@RequestMapping(value = "/garages/a/brand", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
```